# VBA: "Argument not optional", but my function has no parameters?

Tags: vba, excel

I am uncertain as to why I'm getting the error, "Argument not optional" when I call a function that has no arguments:

```vb
Sub CreateQACheck()
' ...do stuff
    Dim QAFileName As String
    QAFileName = FindQACheckFile
    '...
End Sub

Function FindQACheckFile() As String
    ' Do stuff...
    FindQACheckFile = something
End Function
```

Should I put unused parameters in there anyway?

EDIT: I figured out the problem (missing parenthesis), and I'll post the answer below, but here is the code where there was an issue:

```
Function FindQACheckFile() As String
    Dim QAFileDir As String, QAFileName As String, QAFilePath As String
    QAFileDir = "c:\something"
    If Len(Dir(QAFileDir)) = 0 Then 
        QAFileDir = "c:\somethingelse"
    End If
    QAFileName = "qacheckfile.xlsm"
    QAFilePath = QAFileDir + QAFileName
    If Len(Dir(QAFilePath)) = 0 Then ' If it's not there, gotta ask the user where it is
        MsgBox ("I can't find the QA check file! Please let " + MGlobal.DEVNAME + " (" + MGlobal.DEVEMAIL + ") know, but for now point me in the right direction...")
        Dim fd As FileDialog
        Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        With fd
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            If .Show = -1 Then
                QAFilePath = .SelectedItems
            End If
        End With
    End If
    FindQACheckFile = QAFilePath
End Function
```

Comment: Check throughout your entire project for some kind of duplicate name (maybe in a module, class, etc...). There is nothing wrong with that specific code, unless something else is interfering..

Comment: Your code looks correct to me. Are you sure you are not getting this error somewhere else? Or have you created multiple functions with same names?

Comment: Tools - Options - General - Error Trapping - Break on All Errors. Turn that option ON. you may be hitting an error in another point that is hidden.

Comment: Instead of saying `' ...do stuff` or `FindQACheckFile = something` Can you show us the exact code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with this line:

```
QAFilePath = .SelectedItems
```

I had forgotten that this is an array, so it should have looked like this:

```
QAFilePath = .SelectedItems(1)
```

I'm not sure why it errored out on the name of the function instead of on that line specifically, though.